# A simple div layout using position

Tags: html, layout, position

Let's see if I can explain this correctly.  I want a header, always visible AND content AND a footer that is hidden behind the content, that becomes visible when scrolled to the footer.  Here's what I have so far...

```css
    #container {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
    }

    #top {
 height:25vh;
 width:100%;
 background-color:red;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
    }

    #content {
 height:120vh;
 width:100%;
 background-color:green;
 position:relative;
    }

    #bottom {
 height:35vh;
 width:100%;
 background-color:blue;
 position:fixed;
 bottom:0;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="container">

 <div id="top">
 
 </div>
 
 <div id="content">
 
 </div>
 
 <div id="bottom">
 
 </div>

    </div>
```

What this code currently does: Header is hidden behind content and footer is always visible overlapping content.

Here is the current test page... http://next-factor.com/test-layout.php

Much help is greatly appreciated.  Thank You!

Comment: add z-index in all 3 css class. z-index help you to manage overlapping

Answer (score 1):

give a `z-index` in `#top`

```
#top {
    background-color: red;
    height: 25vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

it will make header visible.

and remove `position:fixed` from `#bottom`

```
#bottom {
    background-color: blue;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 35vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

hope this will solve your problem

here is the working example http://jsfiddle.net/a3ru9d4d/

in this example I have added padding top in the container so that content inside the container will not hide behind the header.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:-

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0}
#container {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
    }

    #top {
 height:25vh;
 width:100%;
 background-color:red;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 z-index: 1;
    }

    #content {
 height:120vh;
 width:100%;
 background-color:green;
 position:relative;
    }

    #bottom {
 height:35vh;
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
 z-index:-2;
 background-color:#31353a;


    }
```

```html
 <div id="top">
 
 </div>
 
 <div id="content">
 
 </div>
 
  <div id="bottom">
  Footer 
  </div>

    </div>
```

I hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. I've introduced two new CSS definitions that achieve what I think you want.

https://jsfiddle.net/b8my8h5j/

1. I added `z-index` definitions. The higher the index, the higher it is in a non-static positioning stack. the content header has `30`, so it appears above `20` for the content, but the footer has `10`, so t's always at the back.
2. I added a `margin-bottom` to the content so that there's space for you to scroll down and have the footer be completely visible.

Update:
https://jsfiddle.net/b8my8h5j/1/

1. Also cleared padding/margin on the body and html tags so that the blocks fit together snugly.
2. Added a margin-top to the content so that the top of the green box is visible.

Comment: That does appear to be what I want.  Thank You!  But I'm confused as to why the content isn't spanning the whole 100%.  You see the white space to the right of the green?

Comment: I need to read on z-index.  I've always used it when told but never really understood its purpose.

Comment: Look at my update: https://jsfiddle.net/b8my8h5j/1/ -- I removed the page's natural padding and margins so that the elements fit snugly. I also added a margin-top to the content so that the top of the green box is visible.

Comment: I can see it working in JSFiddle but doesn't appear to on the live site.  Is everything here compatible with all browsers or do I need to find compatibility solutions?

Comment: Your page is looking fine to me. Please make sure you've cleared your browser cache. Try pressing [CTRL]+[F5].

Comment: lol.  I didn't have `<!DOCTYPE html>` declared.  That solved the problem and it works fine.  Thank You for the help.  Now to implement this with my actual content.  It'll be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I think this produces what you want: z-indexes on all three, and making room at the bottom of `content` for the footer to show completely when you scroll to the end of the page

```css
#container {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
}

#top {
  height: 25vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}

#content {
  height: 120vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 33vh;
  z-index: 2;
}

#bottom {
  height: 35vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
   <div id="container">

 <div id="top">
 
 </div>
 
 <div id="content">
 
 </div>
 
 <div id="bottom">
 
 </div>

    </div>
```